# Multiple routes on method with parameter in different locations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm translating an old API to .net 7, while at the same time creating some new routes for some methods that make more sense than the old ones, while maintaining the old ones for compatibility.

I have some cases where a parameter is being passed as a query parameter but it would make more sense to pass it as a route parameter. The only way I have found of making this work is by creating two similar methods, one where the parameter is declare with `FromQuery` attribute and another where the parameter is declared with `FromRoute` attribute. Like this:

```
[Route("value")]
public IActionResult GetValue1([FromQuery(Name = "param")] int parameter)
{
    ...
}

[Route("value/{param}")]
public IActionResult GetValue2([FromRoute(Name = "param")] int parameter)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to declare just one instance of this method that would accept the parameter by route or query, or do I have to keep using two separate methods for this?

**[Edit]**

I have created a small project to test this with one method declared like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("string")]
[Route("string/{str}")]
public string GetString(string str)
{
    return $"abc + {str}";
}
```

If I call the method with the route parameter, like this:

```
/string/123
```

then I get the expected reply `abc + 123`.

But if I call the method with a query parameter, like this:

```
/string?str=123
```

then I get an error: `The str field is required.`

If I change the method parameter to be nullable (`string?`) then it does not return an error, but it does not pick up the parameter value from query, it simply returns `abc +` .

Comment: Make the parameter nullable so it is optional?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("string/{str1?}")]
public string GetString([FromRoute]string? str1, [FromQuery]string? str)
{
    if (str1 != null) { str = str1; }
    return $"abc + {str}";
}
```